# What are good online sources for historical maps?

Tags: middle-ages, historiography, maps, cartography

I am looking for good online sources for historical maps, specifically the late medieval period (but other periods would be interesting as well). While there are many historical maps out there, few feature details such as city names, names of smaller states or regions within larger states etc.

Let’s share our links!

Comment: Wouldn't be great, a google maps with a "date" bar added...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is source request, an explicitly excluded type of question.

Comment: While technically off topic, the answers to this question provide a valuable resource that is not readily available elsewhere on the web, accomplishing an explicitly defined goal of the site: to improve that corner of the web dealing with matters of historical interest. I suggest leaving it open, but converting all the answers to *community wiki*.

Answer (score 10):

Some maps from some UK universities can be found [here](http://oldmapsonline.org/).

Comment: Quite extensive, and definitely within the time period asked for by the asker.

Answer (score 10):

Euratlas.net is by far the best map website, it has maps from 1AD to 2000AD. For European maps click [here](http://www.euratlas.net/history/europe/index.html) and for general maps click [here](http://www.euratlas.net/antique/cartography/index.html).

Comment: this does not add maps that are historical, these are modern maps of old boundaries

Comment: yes they do: http://www.euratlas.net/antique/cartography/index.html

Comment: Now it does and those are what I thought OP wanted. I changed my vote.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some sites that I like:

• [Historical maps, University of Texas](http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/)

(more to come)

Answer (score 8):

I realise I am very late in answering this, but I cannot stress this enough: the best source by far for historical maps that I have ever found, is [David Rumseys amazing online collections](http://www.davidrumsey.com/)

I would also like to point you in the direction of this book; [Cartographies of Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1616890584) though it might be more time-space related than what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed Topographical Maps of Bavaria, including complete coverage at 1:50,000 scale during or near the Napoleonic Wars, are available [here](http://www.bayerische-landesbibliothek-online.de/histkarten/suche?buchstabe=D&sortierung=Titel).

Answer (score 2):

The ODP has an entry for [historical maps](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Maps/Historical/).

(The ODP is a directory/catalogue for websites)